# Internal fan on a Dell XPS 1530 stays running post shutdown, am I really getting a shutdown?

Tags: 12.04, laptop, dell, fan, xps

I am loving 12.04LTS, fixed my printer issue, but Now , on my M1530 Dell XPS, my internal fan continues to run following Shutdown.

Shutdown occurs very rapid and I don't really get any confirmation as to where it's at in the shutdown process.

I do have Nvidia and have done the procedure (driver-post release update version activiated).

Has this error been logged elsewhere anyone know ?

Comment: Try holding the power button when you have shutdown and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You MAY be sseing this bug in 12.04, filed specifically on a Dell 1330m though could apply to other Dell laptops with nvidia cards - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/940564

There were 3 possible solutions here on my 1330m with 8400m GS card -

Downgrade nvidia-current to the 290.XX version, packages for 12.04 available here - https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/290.10-0ubuntu2

To downgrade, download the .deb, then use sudo dpkg -i /path/to/nameof.deb

Switch to the nouveau driver which works ok but for many isn't as good. Can be improved a bit by enabling vsync in nouveau which is done in xorg.conf

At least here this only affected a 32 bit install. So dumping that install & starting over with a 64 bit install & shutdowns/restarts have been fine.

Otherwise wait for a new driver version where this doesn't occur, haven't seen one yet here